# Rebuilding failed WDS & MDT server... Do we need to change DNS, DHCP or AD?

Tags: windows-server-2008, imaging, wds, mdt-2010

My colleague and I are experimenting with replacing Ghost with WDS (Server 2008 R2 SE) and MDT 2010. I intially built the virtual machine and added the WDS service but at the time I also imported images directly. My colleague has since added (WAIK and) MDT but now we keep getting various errors trying to deploy images.

It started to get untidy (and we've found a lot more helpful resources since we originally started) so we blew away the VM and have just installed the OS for a fresh start. Before we do anything else though I was just wondering if there are any changes the last install would have made to DNS, DHCP, AD or any other services running in our domain that we should undo before we start again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have DHCP running on the same server?  If you do then you will obviously have to deal with the DHCP, but also just make sure that Option 60 is set to PXEClient.  If the WDS Server was not on a DHCP server then the two DHCP options (and really its only 1) that you will want to take a look at is Option 66 and Option 67. Option 66 is probably the only one you will have to change as its value should be the Boot Server Host Name.  Option 67 is for the Bootfile Name, which avoids making the client having to select what they should boot into.

I'm farily certain nothing is added into AD that would need to be changed as my understanding of how WDS uses AD is to determine whether or not the computer is "Known" (GUID exists in AD) or "Unknown" (GUID does not exist).

Comment: Thanks for that help. And no, it's a separate DHCP server. The main reason I asked is that something I read recently said MDT makes changes to DNS for you...  Found it http://www.slideshare.net/arichardsSaruk/deploying-windows-7-using-wds-and-mdt-2010-8th-july-2010 (slide 2)

Comment: Our main concern was DNS but it turns out it wasn't a problem.